# why this Https Post failed in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, https

I'm simulating an HTTPS process with Google App Engine's URL fetch API. The process has 2 steps: first, a GET request will return an URL with URL-encoded session information and a cookie; and second, a POST with some payload to the returned URL.

I have used Firebug to capture the headers of the 2 requests, e.g User-agent, Keep-alive, Connection, Cookie. I used these same headers in my code (the cookie value is updated according to the response). Testing on my computer is successful but the code always fails at the POST step on Google's server. On my development box, the remote .NET app website replies to the POST request with a 200-OK with the information that I want, but on Google side, the remote .NET app website also give a 200-OK response but with a "Session timeout" message (which I don't want). So what have I missed?

Comment: What's the actual message? Can you include it in your question? And are you using sessions? How are you signing in from the app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connectiong to the GAE applictation through appspot.com domain or a custom domain? [SSL is supported only on appspot.com](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#httpsapps), so maybe this the reason?

Comment: No, I used the API from appspot.